# How to Split a list into sublists grouping by elements

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This is a similar question to [This previus question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq) but in my case I don't know how many items I have to put in each list.

I have a Class "Items" with this properties

```
public class Items{
    public Id { get; set;}
    public String ItemA { get; set;}
    public String ItemB { get; set;}
    public String ItemC { get; set;}
    public String ItemD { get; set;}
    public String ItemE { get; set;}
}
// And a List of Items
List<Items> ....
```

This list has these values:

[image: List of Values]

How can I Split this List into a new `List<List<Items>>` Grouping by ItemA and ItemB?
In this example the expected result whould be:

```
List[0] = {1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
          {4, 10, 20, 31, 40, 12}
List[1] = {2, 10, 19, 30, 40, 50}
List[2] = {3, 9, 20, 40, 30, 50},
          {5, 9, 20, 30, 40, 50},
          {6, 9, 20, 41, 40, 12}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have used to try to achieve this.

Comment: LINQ has an aptly named method `GroupBy()`...

Comment: My mistake was I've forgotten the grp => grp.ToList(); Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `GroupBy` and create an anonymous class with the properties you want to group on.

```
var result = yourList.GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemA, x.ItemB })
                     .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, I was forgetting the .Select(grp => grp.ToList()). :) I need more coffee....Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Grouping Made Easy with LINQ**

You can take advantage of LINQ's built-in [`Enumerable.GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method by supplying an anonymous object to group by :

```
// This will group your rows using the values in ItemA and ItemB
var grouped = input.GroupBy(i => new { i.ItemA, i.ItemB })
                   .ToList();
```

This would break your existing collection into the three distinct groupings that you are looking for, each one containing an `IEnumerable<Items>` that contains each of the ones within that group.

**If You Need Integers...**

If you wanted to actually retrieve the integer values for your strings (as all of your properties are currently strings), you might consider explicitly parsing them as such or writing a method that will return your expected values as an integer array :

```
public class Items
{
    // Omitted for brevity

    public int[] ToIntegerArray()
    {
        return new int[]{ 
           Int32.Parse(Id), 
           Int32.Parse(ItemA), 
           Int32.Parse(ItemB), 
           Int32.Parse(ItemC), 
           Int32.Parse(ItemD), 
           Int32.Parse(ItemE) 
        };  
    }
}
```

This would allow you to then change your code to only output the actual values as opposed to your collections of `Items` objects :

```
// This will group your rows using the values in ItemA and ItemB and map
// each of the inner groupings to an array of integer values
var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(i => new { i.ItemA, i.ItemB }) 
                        .Select(g => g.Select(ig => ig.ToIntegerArray()))
                        .ToList();
```

**Example**

[image]

You can [see a complete working example of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fpKaTH).